# File transfer speeds different depending on direction of file transfer Windows-Ubuntu 13.4

Tags: networking, 13.04, windows-7, samba

I have a small home network with an Ubuntu 13.4 HTPC attached to a gigabit switch in one room and a Win7 PC attached to another gigabit switch in another room.

On Ubuntu:

Simple cut and paste file transfers pushed from HTPC to Win7 are consistently 10-15MB/sec.

Simple cut and paste file transfers pulled from Win7 to HTPC are consistently 20-30MB/sec.

On Win7:

Simple cut and paste file transfers pulled from HTPC to Win7 start at 115MB/s and stabilize at 40MB/s.

Simple cut and paste file transfers pushed from Win7 to HTPC start at 115MB/s and stabilize at 60MB/s.

My test was a single 3GB video file cut and pasted back and forth many times but all my daily video file transfers show similar speeds. None of the other network devices are active at the time of the test, just a straight wired ethernet transfer across 2 switches from PC to PC.

Is this normal? Shouldn't I expect the Ubuntu controlled file transfers to go faster? I would accept 30MB/s but most of my transfers are in the 15MB/s direction.

I am a Ubuntu novice, my setup is fairly vanilla with just MythTV installed beyond the basics.

What more information do I need to supply to track down this issue? (include instructions, I might not know how to do what you ask)

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 will install by default samba 3.6, the latest release of samba (4) adds some speed improvements available on Windows 7/8 and server versions higher than 2008 r2. Could you remove the package samba, install samba4 and check if the speeds you measure are the same?

Comment: Also, **PUSH** is controlled by the receiving workstation. It may be treated as raw data (replacing all time/dates stamps, permissions) and may also do *buffering* in a different pattern to the sender.

Comment: I am running Samba 3.6 but I can't find any good instructions on how to install Samba 4 so we will have to work within the bounds of Samba 3.6.